# cfdocument issue with performance

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument, cfpdf

I am generating a pdf using `cfdocument` and it is working perfectly with this code:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" fontembed="true" saveAsName="file1" mimetype="application/pdf" localUrl="true">
    <cfoutput>
        #response.filecontent# 
        <cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
           #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#
        </cfdocumentitem>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

If I include the `#session.footer#` variable inside it, it takes a lot of time to generate the PDF.

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" fontembed="true" saveAsName="file1" mimetype="application/pdf" localUrl="true">
    <cfoutput>
        #response.filecontent# 
        #session.footer#
        <cfdocumentitem type="footer"> 
           #cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of #cfdocument.totalpagecount#
        </cfdocumentitem>
    </cfoutput>
</cfdocument>
```

The footer variable contains a complete footer section which I want to add at the end of the document. I am don't understand why it is this is taking so much longer. I am using ColdFusion 10.

Comment: I would point you to Ben Nadel's http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1949-the-content-of-this-document-process-takes-more-than-60000-milliseconds-to-process.htm. The comment section is where to look. A lot of people having slow cfdoc issues trace it to their images, sometimes absolute urls (`http...`) vs relative urls (`/....`)

Comment: Without knowing what's *in* `session.footer`, it's rather hard to make sensible commentary on this, yes?

Comment: Definitely, more information to what is contained in that variable would be nice. To find that blog entry, I literally just googled `cfdocument slow`.

Comment: does `session.footer` contain `<img>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the PDF using cfdocument, and then applying the footer using cfpdf as a second process? As with the above comments, it could be what is held in the session variable as well.

I would have left this as a comment instead of a solution, but StackOverflow wont let me :(

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file. Someone had changed the IP from 127.0.0.1 to some local intranet IP and the names server from localhost to the DNS server name. I found that just changing the IP back to 127.0.0.1 was enough. Pdfs had gone from very quick to over 3 minutes. With the change, they were back to quick.
(found this per a comment in https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1121909)